# Dartで数値参照文字（NCR・numeric character reference）のデコードをしたい

Tags: dart

Dartでhtmlファイルを読み込んで、そこに含まれている数値参照文字をデコードしたいです。
検索などで調べてみましたが、（検索の仕方が悪いのか？）情報が少なすぎて、変換の方法がわかりません。

変換前　`&#12486;&#12473;&#12488;`
変換後　テスト

変換の方法、使えるライブラリ、なんでもいいのでアドバイスいただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これはそのデータをリストに変換し、以下の方法でStringに戻すんです、詳しくはグーグルで以下の関数を検索してください

```
String.fromCharCodes(list);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。これをもとにHTMLに含まれているバイト列だけを変換するモジュールを作成できました。

Comment: どういだしまして